# Send a RestTemplate.postForEntinty() using Json objects as header and body of the post request

Tags: java, spring-boot, gson

Is there a way to convert existing java objects to Json objects and send those Json objects as request header and request body in **RestTemplate.postForEntinty()**. I have a functionality where I need to map class name and class properties to the names used in the external APIs request headers and request body payload, class names and properties name are different and can't be written as same. I can only think of converting java objects to Json objects and then sending those objects for exact mapping.

Trying to do somehing like below, but I haven't been successful so far:

```
public Map<String, Object> getApiData(Header headers, Body body){
Gson gson = new Gson();

HttpEntity<?> request = new HttpEntity<>(gson.toJson(headers), gson.toJson(body));
String url = "end point url";
ResponseEntity<String> response = restConnector.postForEntinty(url, request, String.class);

}
```

The above function already takes populated java objects (headers and body. Need to convert these objects to Json objects. I have used **com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty** to map class properties with the api properties, my assumption is after converting the java objects to Json objects I will be able to map class properties with the property names used in the API request.

What should be my approach to tackle this scenario, Am I thinking in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess you can try Jackson ObjectMapper.

This might resolve your problem.

Please follow below link.
[ObjectMapper](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html#jackson-objectmapper-example)